# What are Defender points?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When you are in a Warzone, you can earn "Defender Points". What exactly are they? How are they computed? What are they good for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This thread.](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=72508) does a good job of explaining how points are calculated.

In short it seems that badges and points just show how much / how proficient you are in the PVP Warzones. Points are awarded for hurting opponents, healing allies, and whether you are attacking or defending in the zone at the time.

I hope this go some way to explaining what you wanted to know :)

Answer (score 0):

As near as I've been able to determine, you automatically accumulate defender points at a certain rate if you're standing near an objective your side owns.

Unfortunately, you don't get to see your actual points score go up so I can't tell you if they go up faster when you're also fighting enemies at the same time.

Comment: From the links I found, it seems that your defender or attacker points go up depending on what *side* of the mission you are on, how much healing you do for your team, and how much damage you do to the opponents.